# Airflow schedule interval with ExternalTaskSensor

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm trying to set up airflow with two dags on an interval of "every 30 minutes".

The first dag (*extract*) looks like this:

> extract_table_user_schema >> extract_table_user_data >> finish_extract_table_user

[image: extract dag]

The second dag (*transform*) looks like this:

> sensor_wait_for_finish_extract_table_user >> transform_table_user >> finish_transform_table_user

[image: transform dag]

For both dags I've set up the schedule_interval to `"*/30 * * * *"`

The ExternalTaskSensor is set up with `execution_delta=timedelta(minutes=30)`

My expected flow of the tasks would be: at first the *extract* dag is run. Then, after the dummy task `finish_tranform_table_user` is successful the sensor is triggered and the tasks in *transform* are run.

It just runs fine for the first time, but when I wait for the second run the tasks interrupt themself.
I've observed the *extract* dag being interupted by the `transform_table_user` task which changes some column names. This results in a failed `extract_table_user_data` since the column names do not match any more.

**Edit:** to be more specific what are the expected & occurring results

First, the rundown what each task is supposed to do:

(sql)`extract_table_user_schema`: copies the schema from the user table

(sql)`extract_table_user_data`: copies data from the source table user into the copy of that table

(dummy)`finish_extract_table_user`: dummy task

(sensor)`sensor_wait_for_finish_extract_table_user`: sensor to wait until the extract is finished

(sql)`transform_table_user`: renames a column field from `id` to `user_id`

(dummy)`finish_transform_table_user`: dummy task

Now, the first time the dags are run the result is a copied schema + data and a renamed field. All tasks as successful
The second time the dags are run, one tasks fails and one task is not run. The other are all successful.
The task `extract_table_user_data` fails with the error message; no such field as `id`.
The task `finish_extract_table_user` was not run

The resulting table was a copied schema but no data *and* a renamed field.

So I assume the task `transform_table_user` was run right after the schema was copied. Maybe the set `execution_delta=timedelta(minutes=30)` is wrong somehow? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the api doc for the sensor?

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: This seems to be a bit unclear to me. Shouldn't the dummy task be `finish_extract_table_user`? Also, how are the DAGs run - manually or automatic? Also, what column names are you talking about, is there some kind of schema we need to know about? It would also be very very helpful to have both of the DAG code as well in the question.

Comment: Hey tobi6, the DAGs are run automatic every 30 minutes. Tis is basically for testing since the real app will have an interval more or less at 6h. When I can't get it to work at 30 minutes, it probably won't work at 6h. The schema is not relevant too. For test purposes it is only renaming a column from `id` to `user_id`.

Comment: What does interrupt themselves mean?

Comment: @tobi6 I've added an edit to my post. Hope that clears that up